# UPDATE With Top is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi I am trying to `Update Column` in a `table` with  Different s`tatic date values`.
I try to do an `update` statement like below

```
UPDATE  f 
SET  f.CLOSEDATE = '2016-10-23'
FROM office  f
inner join
(
select OFFICEID from paroffice
where active = 1
and RowStatus ='A'
AND DistrictID = 50000
)ofc
on ( f.OfficeID = ofc.OfficeID)
where CloseDate IS NOT NULL
```

But I am getting

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Error. I googled and found this syntax is correct for `updating` specific numbers of `rows`.  What I am missing here?

Thank you

Comment: That error does not apply to this query.  You have no scalar subqueries in the query.

Comment: But I am getting the same Error

Comment: do you have a trigger in your table?

Comment: i have to check that...thanks

Comment: @Lamak. Thanks I have a trigger in the table...which causes the problem

Comment: yeah, figured it would be that, since your current query wouldn't show that error message

Answer (score -1):

Try writing it without the subquery (and unnecessary parentheses)

```
UPDATE  f 
SET  f.CLOSEDATE = '2016-10-23'
FROM office  f
inner join paroffice ofc
  on  f.OfficeID = ofc.OfficeID
where f.CloseDate IS NOT NULL
and ofc.active = 1
and ofc.RowStatus ='A'
AND ofc.DistrictID = 50000
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way

```
UPDATE  f 
SET  f.CLOSEDATE = '2016-10-23'
FROM office  f
where exists 
(
select 1 from paroffice
inner join f.OfficeId = officeid
where active = 1
and RowStatus ='A'
AND DistrictID = 50000
)
and CloseDate IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query should be fine.  But, you don't need the subquery at all:

```
update  f 
    set  f.CLOSEDATE = '2016-10-23'
    from office f inner join
         paroffice p
         on p.OfficeId = p.OfficeId
    where p.active = 1 and p.RowStatus ='A' and p.DistrictID = 50000 and
          f.CloseDate IS NOT NULL;
```